# Magento 2 Commerce Cloud accessing DB

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

I am working on a project based on Magento Commerce Cloud.

Can anyone please guide me on how can I access the database of the staging branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If your goal is to access it using some type of GUI client, you could accomplish this by opening an ssh tunnel using the `magento-cloud` utility, similar to the above answer:

`magento-cloud tunnel:open --project=<PROJECT_ID> --environment=staging`

Then run the command `magento-cloud tunnel:info` to get the appropriate credentials to input into whatever utility you may be trying to use.

[edited] syntax error on "tunnel:open"

Comment: Can you configure something like dbeaver to connect to mysql across a ssh tunnel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dbeaver but once the tunnel is open (via the cli tool), any client should be able to connect through it.  `magento-cloud tunnel:info` will give the connection information which would have a port on localhost to connect to as well as a username and password if it is staging or production.

Comment: should be `magento-cloud tunnel:open --project=<PROJECT_ID> --environment=staging` but of course one syntax error requires 10 characters to be edited in order to improve the answer.

Comment: Shorthand arguments: `magento-cloud tunnel:open -p PROJECT_ID -e staging`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

SSH to the Integration environment.

```
magento-cloud ssh
```

Connect to the database.

```
mysql -h <db-host> -P <db-port> -p -u <db-user> <db-name>
```

Comment: Thanks.Do we have any option other than terminal ?

Comment: I think no, as this is managed by aws. I'll update if I got any solution in future

Comment: @S.Venky See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

If you using intellij do the following:

Open a tunnel to your required environment:

```
magento-cloud tunnel:open -e integration
```

You should see similar output to the below:

```
SSH tunnel opened to elasticsearch at: http://127.0.0.1:30003
SSH tunnel opened to redis at: redis://127.0.0.1:30004
SSH tunnel opened to database at: mysql://user:@127.0.0.1:30005/main
```

Copy the MySQL string to the clipboard

```
mysql://user:@127.0.0.1:30005/main
```

In Intellij, create a mysql datasource, under the general tab, locate the "URL:" input and paste the mysql string in after the **jdbc:** text.

Final result should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://user:@127.0.0.1:30005/main
```

[image]

Click test connection, you should see the success message, next click apply and you should be good to go

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ece-tools package for taking a db dump:

```
/vendor/bin/ece-tools‌ db-dump
```

Answer (score 0):

I use dbeaver software.  It gives you a visual editor

> Once the tunnel is open (via the cli tool), any client should be able to connect through it. `magento-cloud tunnel:info` will give the connection information

https://dbeaver.io/

Connect to MySQL server in Dbeaver

Create new connection button

Select MySQL

In the ‘General’ window this is ‘User name’ and ‘Password’ for databse

User name: MYSQL user name you want to use

Password: Password of the MYSQL user

When you have already filled the required fields click to Next button. After it the second important window appears:

First of all click to the checkbox icon ‘Use SSH Tunnel’ to gain access to the settings. Fields you have to fill in the right way:

HOST/IP: IP of details shown by magento command

User Name: ssh connection user name you want to use as tunnel to MySQL connection

Authentication Method: ‘Public Key’

Private Key: Path of the private key on your PC

Password: ssh tunnel connection password

If everything has configured correctly when you click to ‘Test Connection’ a confirmation message box will appear.